# Run a python script with NodeJS causing problems

Tags: python, node.js

My python script has **two** main steps:

Open two *webbrowser tabs* (default browser). And let a *LED blink*.

When i am executing the python script via shell with "python netflix.py" everything works fine. 
But when i am trying to start it via my (see below) NodeJS script. Only the LED will be blink. The webbrowser tabs won't come up.

Does anyone know where the issue is?

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 1208;


var http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        try{
        console.log('Request incoming...');  
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

        if(request.url == '/abort'){
                console.log('Calling abort.py ...');
                var process = spawn('python',["./abort.py"]);
        }else{
                console.log('Calling netflix.py');
                var process = spawn('python',["./netflix.py"]);
        }       
}catch(e){
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(e);
        }
});

server.on('error', function(){
        console.log('error');
});


const port = 8000;
server.listen(port);
server.timeout = 10000;
console.log(`Listening at http://leitner-pi:${port}`);
```

---

```
import sys
import webbrowser
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep
try:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://netflix.com");
finally:
        print("")       

print("Lasse PIN 7 blinken..")
led = LED(17)
while True:
        led.on()
        sleep(0.3)
        led.off()
        sleep(0.3)
```

Comment: Do you see both the `Calling abort.py ...` and `Calling netflix.py` messages in the console?

Comment: Depending on the request, but yes. Both.

Comment: Can you add a `except` clause before the finally line in your python script and see if you are ignoring any errors?

Comment: A `try/finally` block without an `except` will not ignore exceptions; they still happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Well, I made a workaround.

First, I split the python script into two scripts. Webbrowser and LED script, to avoid any kind of interruptions or something else. Second, I changed the webbrowser to:

```
os.system(‘sudo -upi chromium-browser URL1 URL2’).
```

At last, I am calling both new 
scripts from my node webserver, like I used before. 
Now it works fine.